# Активная ссылка при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript

Есть одностраничный сайт с прокруткой вниз, причём при нажатии на пункт меню загружается соответсвующий якорь и подсвечивается активная ссылка.

Как сделать, чтобы подсвечивалась активная ссылка ещё и при прокрутке страницы?

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.menu_txt li a').click(function () {
            $('.menu_txt li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            return true;
        });
    });  
</script>

<div id="content">
    <ul class="menu_txt">
      <li><a href=""></a></li>
      <li><a href=""></a></li>
      <li><a href=""></a></li>
      <li><a href=""></a></li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема не решена. Неужели никто не знает как можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Советую не заморачиваться с javascript, а использовать html5 тег <section>.
В качестве примера [Тут](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/)

**UPD:**

Если еще не нашел ответ, то:
Тег <section> это секция которой ты даешь имя и позже обращаешься к этой секции через #имя_секции как ссылки тег a name=""

Если все еще непонятно, гляди еще один [пример](http://gentleman.kz) там и исходники можешь откопать все открыто ведь.

Comment: Не понял как тег section замещает javascript? Может всё-таки кто-то знает как такое реализовать?

Comment: @deitel это ваш сайт ? там  heartbleed

Comment: Нет не мой, знакомого, спасибо я ему скажу.

Comment: Но разве здесь не через javascript? Т.к. при прокрутке нужной ссылке присваевается класс active, а без него не работает? Да и тег <section> принадлежит не самому меню. Не до конца понимаю как это работает и через что, можно подробнее?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно это то что нужно: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gHoAt/?editors=001